# Responsive video background: Video alignment

Tags: html, css, video

I want to create a responsive background video, but don't know how to change the alignment.
As far as I can see, the alignment currently is bottom right, but I want to change it to center center. (like background-position: center center)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66dLhjxh/

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    background-color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: to have it top left just change those right and bottom attributes to top and left

Comment: OK, that was surpassingly simple! Is there any way to center it?

Answer (score 0):

try this code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/mburdo/pen/lfaBk)

```
<div id="info">
Responsive Youtube embed......
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="video-container">

  </div>
  </div>
<button onclick="nextVideo()">Next Video</button>
</div>

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 30px; /* size of chrome */
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container #overlay,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    /*background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); or just this*/
    z-index:50;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: The code that you show only sets the width as the 'rule' for it's height, which causes whitespace when centering too small: And the whitespace only occurs in the bottom of the element, so then the video's not centered if I'm not wrong.

Comment: there still is following links at the bottom for another project , you watched it ?

Comment: That's the same link as your first comment? It seems so anyway, still the whitespace ;).

Answer (score 0):

with this is perfect

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    background-color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    /*background-position: 30% 50%;*/
}
```

[**See it in action.**](http://jsfiddle.net/66dLhjxh/2/)

Comment: It's not centering? Not in the fiddle at least?